# Trying to eliminate redundant code execution for validation and entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redundancy, asp.net-validators

I'm looking to see if there is a way to eliminate one of the two calls that gets made to my method to google maps to calculate long/lat coordinates.

Here is my method.

```
    public static GeocoderCoordinates GetCoordinates(string region)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(region));

       using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
       {
          using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
          {
             XDocument document = XDocument.Load(new StreamReader(stream));

             XElement longitudeElement = document.Descendants("lng").FirstOrDefault();
             XElement latitudeElement = document.Descendants("lat").FirstOrDefault();

             if (longitudeElement != null && latitudeElement != null)
             {
                return new GeocoderCoordinates
                {
                   Longitude = Double.Parse(longitudeElement.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                   Latitude = Double.Parse(latitudeElement.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                };
             }
          }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The first time I call this method it's for validation.

```
internal class ValidateLocationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var location = value as string;

        GeocoderCoordinates coordinates = Geocoding.GetCoordinates(location);
        if (coordinates == null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

and if there is no location that gets found it returns null - validation fails.
The second time it gets called is in the controller to set longitude/latitude coordinates within my entity.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EditStudentViewModel viewModel)
    {   
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Student student = studentRepository.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());

            if (student == null)
            {
                var newStudent = new Student
                {
                    AspNetUserRefId = viewModel.AspNetUserRefId,
                    CatchPhrase = viewModel.CatchPhrase,
                    StartedPracticing = Convert.ToInt16(viewModel.SelectedYearId),
                    LocationPoints = Geocoding.GetDbGeography(viewModel.Location),
                    Location = viewModel.Location,
```

SO I'm running through this method twice just to insert/update a student. It seems a little redundant.

Isn't there a way to trigger/set validation state while the code in the controller is running, so I don't have to call this method twice (once for validation and once to set the actual values) when the user submits the form?

I thought about caching but don't think it's a good idea, unless someone can point out something.

Comment: I do not find another call to GetCoordinates.

Comment: Where are you applying ValidateLocationAttribute?

Comment: I'm applying it to a viewmodel memeber that gets shown in the view. It's a text box...So the user enters in a location ex. San Francisco, and the validation method runs. Then if all validation passes the controller action method runs and it calls the geolocation method again to get the location and set the long/lat values before it submits to the db

Answer (score 0):

If you think applying validation upfront using an attribute on the text box serve value to the user (early feedback), keep things as it is. Two calls is not too bad at all considering the value and cleanliness of the solution.

Second option is you can remove the attribute, and perform the validation in the controller action. If validation fails, display same form with all the same data but error message for the text box value (location). User will need to choose another location and then submit.

It is a trade off.

**Important Tip**: You can optimize your solution by storing region names in your DB and going to google API only if the region name does not present in your DB.